# WinCe PlaySound does not work every time

Tags: c++, windows-ce

I have a problem with my device WinCE 5.0. I need to play sound from resource.

```
BOOL PlayResource (int lpName) 
{ 
  BOOL bRtn; 
  LPTSTR lpRes; 
  HANDLE hResInfo, hRes; 
  HINSTANCE     hInst = AfxGetInstanceHandle();

  // Find the wave resource.
  hResInfo = FindResource (hInst, MAKEINTRESOURCE(lpName), L"WAVE"); 

  if (hResInfo == NULL) 
  {
      filePlay = false;
    return FALSE; 
  }
  // Load the wave resource. 
  hRes = LoadResource (hInst, HRSRC(hResInfo)); 

  if (hRes == NULL) 
  {
      filePlay = false;
    return FALSE; 
  }
  // Lock the wave resource and play it. 
  lpRes = (LPTSTR)LockResource (hRes);

  if (lpRes != NULL) 
    { 
    bRtn = PlaySound(lpRes,GetModuleHandle(NULL), SND_MEMORY | SND_SYNC  | SND_NODEFAULT); 
    DWORD err = GetLastError();
    Logger::getInstance().log(Logger::LOG_INFO, "PlaySound return: %d error: %d", bRtn, err);
    } 
  else 
    bRtn = 0; 

  filePlay = false;
  return bRtn; 
}
```

PlaySound does not work every time. bRtn return 1 every time, but sound not play every time. 
GetLastError() all time get code 120

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
bRtn = PlaySound(lpRes,GetModuleHandle(NULL), SND_MEMORY | SND_SYNC  | SND_NODEFAULT);
```

either to

```
bRtn = PlaySound(lpRes, NULL, SND_MEMORY | SND_SYNC  | SND_NODEFAULT);
```

or to

```
bRtn = PlaySound(MAKEINTRESOURCE(lpName), hInst, SND_RESOURCE | SND_SYNC  | SND_NODEFAULT);
```

in the last case you even don't need to load the sound into memory before calling `PlaySound`.